# g++ errors on try/catch block for exception

Tags: c++, exception, g++, try-catch

Code compiles just fine with VS and Xcode, but of course g++ doesn't like it. I've been staring at this for hours and am just circling the drain. Theres good Karma in this one! :)

Here is the version of g++ I'm using:

```
[...]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
```

Here is the code:

```
Item* Library::findItem(unsigned int hash) {

//retrieve reference to Items::AllItems
std::map<unsigned int, Item*>& allItems = MyItems.getItems();

Item* item = NULL;

try {
    item = allItems.at(hash);
}
//LINE 74 BELOW: the catch line
catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    return NULL;
}
return item;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
library.cpp: In member function ‘Item* Library::findItem(unsigned int)’:
library.cpp:74: error: expected `(' before ‘{’ token
library.cpp:74: error: expected type-specifier before ‘{’ token
library.cpp:74: error: expected `)' before ‘{’ token
```

Comment: What exactly is at line 74?

Comment: I'll hazard a guess: GCC 4.1.2 is from 2007, so it doesn't have support for C++11 features, and std::map::at was introduced with C++11. You could use std::map::find instead of std::map::at and ditch the try / catch block altogether.

Comment: Line 74 is the line with 'catch' on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the same error without the include:

```
//#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {}
    catch(const std::out_of_range&) {}
}
```

g++ 4.7.2

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Program compiles and runs just fine. All I needed to do was add the include. GEEZ!

Answer (score 0):

I'll turn my comment into an answer. I suppose that GCC is actually complaining about the use of `std::map::at`, which was [introduced with C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) and is therefore not supported by GCC 4.1.2, which was [released in 2007](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.1/). I would rewrite the code like so:

```
Item* Library::findItem(unsigned int hash) {
    std::map<unsigned int, Item*>& allItems = MyItems.getItems();
    const std::map<unsigned int, Item*>::iterator it = allItems.find(hash);
    if (it == allItems.end())
        return NULL;
    return it->second;
}
```